# Need additional loaders in angular 8

Tags: angular

ERROR in ./src/app/user/user-view/add-guest/guest.service.ts 30:25

Module parse failed: Invalid number (30:25)

File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

|                 time: new Date('10/25/1998'),

|                 members: 1,

> ```
>             contact: 0934222966,
> ```

|                 idType: 'Pan Card',

|                 idNo: 'DVTPS2462D',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0934222966` starts with 0, so it's supposed to be an octal number. But octal numbers can't contain the digit 9, by definition.

You probably want a string, not an octal number. So there should be quotes: `contact: '0934222966'`.